# GPS receiver compatible with NTP

Tags: gps

I have long wanted a GPS receiver that is either integrated with an NTP server, or compatible with a device like a Raspberry PI, including PPS signals.

Until a few years ago, you could only go buy an integrated unit for $2000-$6000, including an oven controlled crystal.  While this is appropriate for a large enterprise server, I'm wanting one for home use.

More recently, I have found $300 units.

What I am looking for is a $15 to $35 (or maybe to $50) unit.  Any suggestions?

## Edits:

The purpose here is to run a stratum 1 NTP server.  This would then provide time to all my computers.  I would like NTP precision of at least 15 (30 microseconds).   19 or 20 (2 or 1 microseconds) would be better.

I am expecting I will have to assemble something with a Raspberry PI or Beagle Bone, but would prefer a prebuilt unit if anyone knows of one.

Obviously, a serial interface will not get that precision, but the PPS interface can.  PPS is pulse per second, a once per second microsecond precise pulse usually connected to an interrupt on a host computer (or ignored if you don't care about time precision).

#### Related rants:

It would be nice if adafruit hadn't decided to only support one expensive GPS.

It would be nice if there were a SOC including a CPU and GPS, so the CPU could read the GPS time registers directly.   That might achieve an NTP precision of 26 (16 nanosecond or about 5 meters).

Comment: What kind of precision are you aiming to achieve? You could probably achieve a decent precision using GPS PPS and regular NTP on any SBC with UART, GPIO and an internet connection (preferably wired, not mobile)

Comment: 15 what? For 15 milliseconds a good internet is probably enough. 15 microseconds is unrealistic in your budget. For PPS you get any GPS receiver which outputs it on a GPIO and configure it via the device tree.

Comment: honestly, I doubt you could get 30 microseconds with USB, not to mention UART. I once read up on cable providers and they typically they have around 50 us in their server rooms, for combined cable+DOCSIS

Comment: you get your clock working with microsecond precision once set properly. But that initial setting of time will not be more precise than a couple milliseconds in your budget. For a system to reach a given precision each part needs to be at least that precise. If all you need is a clock that ticks precisely even if the actual time is a few milliseconds off than save yourself the trouble and get a good RTC and connect it using I2C or SPI.

Comment: @JanDorniak my half of discussion, and motivation, incorporated into the question